# I have a jquery issue. I have two divs showing and hiding. Both are set to refresh but one is overriding it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jquery issue I have two divs showing and hiding and both are set to refresh but one is over riding the other. I am not sure why the load1 were div1 is at keeps overriding the load2 div2. so when i click on button completed the received div is automatically refreshing and changing the page back to received. I will try to get this on fiddle.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <title></title>

           <link href="http://localhost/test/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
           <link href="http://localhost/test/assets/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
           <link href="http://localhost/test/assets/css/custom_edit.css" rel="stylesheet">
           <link href="http://localhost/test/assets/datatables/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->


        </head>
        <body>
         <pre><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="received">Received</button><button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" id="completed">Completed</button></pre>

        <div id="load1">
          <div id="div1">
           <h3>Received Section</h3>
             //code goes here......

          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="load2">
             <input type="hidden" id="show_completed" value="1" name="show_completed">
         <div id="div2">
          <h3>Completed Section</h3>
            //code goes here......

         </div>
        </div>
        <footer>
          <script src="http://localhost/test/assets/jquery/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://localhost/test/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://localhost/test/assets/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://localhost/test/assets/datatables/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>


      <script type="text/javascript">
     var $show_completed = document.getElementById('show_completed');

        if($show_completed.value == '0')
        {

        setInterval(function() {
            $("#load1").load(location.href+" #load1>*","");
        }, 10000); // seconds to wait, miliseconds

        }
        else($show_completed.value == '1')
        {

        setInterval(function() {
            $("#load2").load(location.href+" #load2>*","");
        }, 100000); // seconds to wait, miliseconds

        }

        </script>


          <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready( function () {
              $('#div2').fadeOut();
          } );
          $("#received").on('click', function() {
          document.getElementById("show_completed").value='0';
           $("#div1").fadeIn();
           $("#div2").fadeOut();


        });
        $("#completed").on('click', function() {
          document.getElementById("show_completed").value='1';
           $("#div2").fadeIn();
           $("#div1").fadeOut();
        });

        </script>
        </footer>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, so what exactly happens that is not supposed to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Try this... Hope it helps

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link href="http://localhost/test/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="http://localhost/test/assets/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="http://localhost/test/assets/css/custom_edit.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="http://localhost/test/assets/datatables/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://localhost/test/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://localhost/test/assets/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://localhost/test/assets/datatables/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="received">Received</button>
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" id="completed">Completed</button>
        </pre>

        <div id="load1">
            <div id="div1">
                <h3>Received Section</h3>
                //code goes here......
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="load2">
            <input type="hidden" id="show_completed" value="1" name="show_completed">
            <div id="div2">
                <h3>Completed Section</h3>
                //code goes here......
            </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var $show_completed = document.getElementById('show_completed');

            if($show_completed.value == '0'){
                setInterval(function() {
                    $("#load1").load(location.href+" #load1>*","");
                }, 10000); // seconds to wait, miliseconds
            } else($show_completed.value == '1'){
                setInterval(function() {
                    $("#load2").load(location.href+" #load2>*","");
                }, 100000); // seconds to wait, miliseconds
            }
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready( function () {
                $('#div2').fadeOut();
            });

            $("#received").on('click', function() {
                document.getElementById("show_completed").value='0';
                $("#div1").fadeIn();
                $("#div2").fadeOut();
            });

            $("#completed").on('click', function() {
                document.getElementById("show_completed").value='1';
                $("#div2").fadeIn();
                $("#div1").fadeOut();
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: moving scripts does not help. The scripts can be in the footer. The code works but not correct due to the if statement on my setInterval function . for some reason the first setInterval is working but my second is not the first one is over riding the page making the page reload even when I click the completed button. This is a bit tricky.

Comment: i can't delete this question i decided to just use iframes for the refresh i was hoping to avoid doing that